# vbscript copy text from specified line to EOF

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm looking for a way to copy from specified line to the EOF?
I have two or more text.log which are filled from time to time and I need to append all these data to one textall.log but remembering the last line in text.log because otherwise are copied again all data in textall.log.

Comment: Your question/problem is very unclear. Can you provide some examples or otherwise elaborate on the specific problem you are having?

Comment: Ok, I have a file, text.log with 3 lines completed and another text1.log with 4 lines completed and these two files should be append to the main file textall.log ( 7 lines of logs). In the next 10 minutes in text.log was written other 3 line and in text1.log other 4 lines. In this moment I need to be appended only last 3 respective 4 lines to textall.log not all, 6 respective 8 line because in this way at every 10 minutes the data from textall.log will be multiplicand.I like to believe that now I was clear! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So - it would appear you wish to accumulate all of the updates to *.log into textall.log

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET "history=q28129095.history"

PUSHD "%sourcedir%"

:: force history file to eist
ECHO(>>"%history%"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "*.log" '
 ) DO IF /i "%%a" neq "textall.log" (
  SET "filename=%%a"
 REM find lines in target logfile
  FOR /f "tokens=2delims=:" %%q IN ('find /c /v "" "%%a"') DO SET /a lines=%%q
 REM locate record of this file in history
  SET "hist="
  FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2delims=:" %%q IN ("%history%") DO IF "%%q"=="%%a" SET "hist=skip=%%r"
 REM append new lines to textall.log
  CALL :addlines
)
popd

GOTO :EOF
:addlines
FOR /f "usebackq %hist% delims=" %%q IN ("%filename%") DO >>textall.log ECHO(%%q
:: Now maintain the history file
(FOR /f "delims=" %%r IN ('FINDSTR /V /B /L /c:"%filename%" "%history%"') DO echo(%%r)>"%history%.temp"
:: record new start-line
>>"%history%.temp" ECHO(%filename%:%lines%
MOVE /y "%history%.temp" "%history%" >nul
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

For lack of further information, I've assumed `testxall.log` is in the same directory as all of the logfiles.

You would need to set `history` to a filename (possibly including a pathname) to suit you. This file retains a record of how far has already been recorded to the accumulated log.

You need to consider what would happen if your logfiles are purged - you'd need to maintain the `history` file manually.

Also consider that there's noindication of the source log in the accumulated.

And empty lines will be expunged.

---

Response to problem report

I can't reproduce your symptoms.

The `echo` keyword should not appear in the history file. Note that the coding is very precise - `echo(` not `echo (`. Although traditionally the character following `echo` is a space, there is a set of characters which may succeed the `o` and produce virtually the same result. Of these, `(` is paricularly useful because `echo %something%` where `something` is undefined will report `echo is on/off` but `echo(%something%` where `something` is undefined will produce a new line

This is the result I obtained by running the routine twice; the first time with 4 lines in each of `x1..5.log` and the second with `x5.log` deleted and the others with 6 lines:

```
X5.log:4
X1.log:6
X2.log:6
X3.log:6
X4.log:6
```

What should happen with regard to the history file is:

- An empty line is added at the start by `ECHO(>>"%history%"`
  This should simply ensure the file exists so `findstr` has nothing to complain about
- for each logfile, `hist` is set to *nothing* then the `history` file is examined and tokenised. The `name` is assigned to `%%q` and the `previous-linecount` to %%r. If the filename matches then the `hist` string is set to `skip=(previous-linecount)`
- within the `:addlines` procedure, the `findstr` command allows through all of the lines which do **not** match (/v) the literal (/L) of the filename (/c:"string"), which should remove any existing record for the file `%filename%`. This is mechanically read by a `for/f` command assigning the entire line to `%%r` (because of the `delims=` - and this also removes empty lines.

There is a little technique however that you may have "corrected." The `echo(` I've already covered. As I've coded it, the line then reads

```
(for...etc...echo(%%r)>"temporaryfilename"
```

The parentheses here are important as they serve to output the entire response from `for` into a new file. The name and linecount for the log file are then appended to this tempfile and it's renamed for the next cycle.

**I've modified** the `findstr` here by adding in a `/b` switch to cause the filename match to be applied at the beginning of the line. In this way, "X2.log" won't delete the record for "anotherlogx2.log" by matching the `x2.log` part.

If you have further trouble, please `edit` your original question to include formatted data if required. As you've seen, using comments doesn't make the situation clear...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It was very useful for me, but I forgot to mention that my sources and destination (textall.log) are on different folders! I will try to figure out how can I change the paths in your script for maximum efficiency!

Comment: If you want to change the location of `textall.log` then simply change `>>textall.log` to `>>"c:\whever\your\required path is\textall.log"` - include the quotes if the path contains spaces, or as a matter of course if you prefer. Required with spaces, optional if not. There's no point in removing the `if /i "%%a" neq "textall.log"` gate because `textall.log` won't exist in the directory beingscanned for `*.log` files.

Comment: I used your hint and now its OK but the history file growing very fast if I use more than 1 log file: _D:\log>echo(D:\log>echo(D:\log>echo(X1.log:4   
D:\log>echo(D:\log>echo(X1.log:4  
D:\log>echo(D:\log>echo(X1.log:4  
D:\log>echo(X1.log:4 
D:\log>echo(D:\log>echo(X1.log:4  
D:\log>echo(X1.log:4 
D:\log>echo(X1.log:4 
X1.log:4
D:\log>echo(D:\log>echo(X2.log:9  
D:\log>echo(X2.log:9 
D:\log>echo(X2.log:9 
X2.log:9
D:\log>echo(X3.log:26 
X3.log:26
X4.log:14_

Comment: The problem was from here: Because I wanted to see what does your script, I changed first line from  `@echo off ` to `@echo on`! I changed back and the problem was solved! :) Thanks again for your support!